# python PDFminer only parses part of the page

Tags: python, parsing, pdf, pdfminer

I am parsing a PDF document using module `pdfminer` python module. I just want to extract text from this document.

The process is going great but, when I extract `LTText*` objects, I realize that I am not getting all the text inside that `LTText*` object. It seems like it has an internal buffer or something like that cause texts being cut in every page.

My code:

```
...
for lt_text_obj in lt_objs:
    if isinstance(lt_text_obj, LTTextBox) or isinstance(lt_text_obj, LTTextLine):
         if lt_text_obj._objs:
             for text_obj in lt_text_obj._objs:
                 if isinstance(text_obj, LTTextBox) or isinstance(text_obj,LTTextLine)]:
                     text_content.append(text_obj)
...
```

The text_obj variable never contains the entire text, even when this text in the page of pdf file is always formatted the same.

I don't think the problem is in the code cause I also converted the pdf file to txt using pdf2txt.py script and the pages of the resulting txt file is also 'cut'.

It seems that the problem may be in pdfminer configuration or in my pdf file format... I am completely lost.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  Or do you know of a mirror for your 'famous example'?  The link is broken.

Comment: The example was not "mine", I edited the post to remove the broken link. What I did is to convert the pdf to txt and deal with it using REGEX

Answer (score 2):

hard to tell without the input pdf, I'd try to run:

```
pdf2txt.py -o output.xml path/to/your_input.pdf
```

this tool is a part of pdfminder and can be very useful for debugging, try to examine the result xml to find the pattern that does not extracted correctly

Answer (score 1):

is it possible for you to use PyPDF2 instead?
I wrote a small "interface" for myself in order to transfer page by page from one pdf-file to another (https://github.com/stianhotboi/pypdf2Interface/blob/master/pypdf2_interface.py). I did not see any problems like yours in my case (all seemed transferred well).

Comment: what exactly was your approach with pyPdf2? I believe that all my text is included (as a pdf page), or is it that your transferring the text elements from the pdf that is the problem? I have to admit that I haven't tried that.

Comment: I got this error while trying to use PyPDF2: https://github.com/colemana/PyPDF2/issues/5 and I could not resolve it :(